# compatibility of c++11 and MPI library

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, c++11, mpi

After installing gcc and mpich library in my linux I can compile my codes with `mpicxx` compiler. Is it possible to use c++11 with mpi library with just upgrading gcc compiler?

Comment: You probably already have a c++11 powered gcc version, check for the `-std=c++11` flag.

Comment: No the gcc version that is installed on my computer doesn't support c++11

Comment: That said, what have you tried? :) My impression is that it should work, because MPI and C++11 features are mostly orthogonal.

Comment: I just read the documentation of gcc

Comment: I suggest to upgrade to gcc 4.7 for better support of C++2011 standard, and I suspect it probably is orthogonal to MPI compatibility

Comment: Are you going to use C++11 threading support? If so, check that your MPI implementation was compiled with support for thread-safe invocation otherwise bad things could happen.

Comment: @HristoIliev yes I'm going to use c++11 threading support.

Comment: Bear in mind that, from MPI-2.2, the C++ bindings are deprecated.  I haven't come across an implementation that has dropped them, yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the compiler with a newer version should work in general unless some strong code generation changes are observed (e.g. different data alignment or different ABIs). MPI is a library and as such it doesn't care what language constructs you are using as long as those constructs don't mess up with its internals. Since you are going to use C++11 for the threading it provides, there are some things that you should be aware of.

First, multithreading doesn't always play nice with MPI. Most MPI implementations are internally threaded themselves but are **not** thread safe by default.

Second, MPI defines four levels of threading support:

- `MPI_THREAD_SINGLE`: no threading support - MPI would function safely only when used by a single-threaded application;
- `MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED`: partial threading support - MPI can be used in a multithreaded application but only the *main thread* may call to MPI;
- `MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED`: partial threading support - MPI can be used in a multithreaded application but no concurrent calls in different threads are allowed. That is, each thread can call into MPI but a serialisation mechanism has to be in place;
- `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE`: full threading support - MPI can be called freely from many threads.

Truth is most MPI implementations support out of the box `MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED` at max with most of them supporting only `MPI_THERAD_SINGLE`. Open MPI for example has to be compiled with a non-default option in order to get the full threading support.

Multithreaded applications should initialise the MPI library using `MPI_Init_thread()` instead of `MPI_Init()` and the thread that makes the initialisation call becomes the *main thread* - the very same *main thread* that is only allowed to call into MPI when the supported level is `MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED`. One gives `MPI_Thread_init()` the *desired* level of threading support and the function returns the *supported* level which might be lower than desired. In the latter case correct and portable programs are supposed to act accordingly and either switch to non-threaded operation or abort with the respective error message to the user.

More information about how MPI works together with threads can be found in the [MPI Standard v2.2](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi22-report/node257.htm).

Answer (score 5):

No problem as far as I can think of, since you shouldn't be able to tamper with the MPI directives in any way, and other than that, MPI and C++11 concerns are orthogonal.

By the way, issuing `mpic++` or `mpicxx` on my machine (gcc 4.6.3, MPICH2 1.4.1) simply translates into

`c++ -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -I/usr/include/mpich2 -L/usr/lib -lmpichcxx -lmpich -lopa -lmpl -lrt -lcr -lpthread`

You can check that on your own machine with `mpic++ -show`.

Answer (score 2):

It is no problem to combine C++11 with MPI.

mpic++ and mpicxx are only wrappers and use either the standard compiler or the user speciifed compiler. So you can define that mpic++ and mpicxx use a compiler with is compatible to C++11.

I do not know the exact command for mpich. For opemmpi you need to set these environment flags:

```
export OMPI_CC='gcc-mp-4.7'
export OMPI_CXX='g++-mp-4.7'
```

In my case I use openmpi 1.5.5 with the gcc 4.7 compiler from macports.